# How to use mysql full text search when title and text are in two separate tables?

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I have a question and answer database that I want my users to be able to search and I want to use a full text search because I've heard it's awesome.

Problem is, I have a table with questions, and then a table with responses that has a many to one relationship to the questions table.

I can do a search on the responses table like so...

```
SELECT response 
FROM helpresponses
WHERE MATCH(response) AGAINST ('quickbooks');
```

but I'd also like to search the question itself because the question may use some keywords that the response doesn't use.

I would rather not duplicate the question in the responses table, but I've read that the match function can not search two tables in one query, so what is the best way to structure this?

Comment: Just use a JOIN, just like any other time when you need to relate two tables. Full-text search doesn't change this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Join the two tables

```
SELECT question, response, 
       (MATCH(response) AGAINST ('quickbooks')) AS response_matches
FROM helpresponses AS r
JOIN helpquestions AS q ON r.questionid = q.id
WHERE MATCH(response) AGAINST ('quickbooks')
OR MATCH(question) AGAINST ('quickbooks')
ORDER BY response_matches DESC
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you!  Now is there a way to prioritize one table over the other?

Comment: I've updated the answer to show how to list the questions where the response matches first.